# Why my DOM parser cant read UTF-8

Tags: java, parsing, dom

I have problem that my DOM parser can´t load file when there are UTF-8 characters in XML file
Now, i am aware that i have to give him instruction to read utf-8, but i don´t know how to put it in my code
here it is:

```
File xmlFile = new File(fileName);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

i am aware that there is method setencoding(), but i don´t know where to put it in my code...

Comment: Does the XML file start with `<?xml ... encoding="UTF-8"?>`?

Comment: @Matt Ball, that is problem.I am writing to file in wrong way, so I cant put that in XML. instead, i would like to write it in java

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Try this. Worked for me**

```
        InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(completeFileName);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
        InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
        is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```

Comment: Glad to hear you found it helpful... :)

Answer (score 7):

Try to use Reader and provide encoding as parameter:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")));
```

Comment: inputsource is in DOM API?

Comment: not working or i dont know how to use it. non static method parse cannot be referenced from a static context sax

Answer (score -2):

I used what Eugene did up there and changed it a little.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("XML.xml"));
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(in, "UTF-8");
```

though this will be read as `UTF-8` if you are printing in eclipse console it won't show any 'UTF-8' characters unless the java file is saved as 'UTF-8', or at least that what happened with me

Comment: The second argument of the method [`DocumentBuilder.parse(InputStream, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-) is a *URI*, not a character encoding. It’s rather strange when providing `UTF-8` there solves any problems…