# Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 Java, sequence error depending on Windows/IntelliJ

Tags: java, xml

So the same code is running on both of the devices, both PCs are running Windows 10, but the variable is represented different in IntelliJ debugger and one can decode string, and other can't. Both are accessing same endpoint. This is code snippet that's throwing error and where code breaks. Both code are running on the same JRE and getting variable value from same endpoint.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(file);
```

As I am generating XML file that's UTF-8 encoded, it throws error for that variable.

Variable that's not throwing error on PC1 shown in debugger

[image: Debugger var not throwing error]

Variable that's throwing error on PC2

[image: Error variable]

I tried reinstalling all JRE, IntelliJ, etc etc, still no help...

Comment: Are you sure IntelliJ IDEA is configured to use the exact same font on both machines, and that the font does in fact exist on both machines, and that the font files are identical?

Comment: @MikeNakis I checked now, they use same font, also both IntelliJ File Encode settings are same enforced by me, but on PC1 system default is windows-1250 and on PC2 system default is windows-1252, tried all File Encoding settings on PC2 IntelliJ, still no help

Comment: What is `file`? If it's a byte based entity such as `InputStream`, you're using the default platform encoding to parse it, giving you different results depending on the encoding. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400136/why-my-dom-parser-cant-read-utf-8

Comment: @Kayaman I tried it that way, application doesn't break that way, but output is still wrong, it doesn't decode character as it should be, it just prints out " �? ". I guess the problem is in variable init, as you can see the variables value is different from it's init, when I parse API's response it is already different, and I am getting APIs response as String, then transforming it to Object

Comment: I don't see any variable named `init`.

Comment: @Kayaman I mean when i give variable folioName initial value, when I assign APIs value to it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file is UTF-8 encoded? In my case I realized it was windows-1250 encoding used. So I had to specify an encoding:

```
InputStream is = ...
InputSource src = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("cp1250")));
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(src);
```